# Session Laravel is remove after refresh

Tags: php, laravel

something weird is happened in Laravel 7.0.8

In FooController I have the next code:

```
// @index
session()->put('foo', 'bar');
session()->save();

dd(session()->all());
```

And all sessions are showing fine. But, if I go to other method

```
// @other
dd(session()->all());
```

Session "foo" is gone. How I can to persistent that?

I try in Laravel 6.* and same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `dd()` otherwise the code will exit and the session won't be saved. Store it normally then check on the session in the other method.